# Delete parameter from query string in one-line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a block of code that removes the `search` element from the query string so I can provide a link to the user to reload the page without and search parameters present.

The code I have to do that takes 6 lines.

```
<%
  url = request.original_url
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  query = Rack::Utils.parse_query(uri.query)
  query.delete('search')
  uri.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(query)
%>
<%= link_to 'Clear search filter', uri.to_s %>.
```

Is there a one-liner to do this in Rails so I only need to `link_to` line?

**Update:** I want to be able to preserve any other query string parameters except the `search` parameter.

Comment: You can give path of same page in link_to

Comment: Does this code live in a view? if so, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: what other parameter (except search) do you have ?

Comment: @TamerShlash Why is it terrible? Where should I put it? Should it be it's own helper or something?

Comment: @Turgs yes, views are not supposed to contain chunks of code like that. This should go in a helper method, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your way totally depends on what exactly is your requirement.
You can achieve this by simply

```
<%= link_to 'Clear search filter', search_path %>
```

If you need any special parameter then pass it wil url

```
<%= link_to 'Clear search filter', search_path(your_required_param/params) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html) with a copy of the current `params` without the `search` key:

```
<%= link_to 'Clear search filter', url_for(params.except(:search)) %>
```